# Data modeling to define productivity metrics

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have a requirement to calculate productivity in our issue tracking software(Jira). Idea is I want to capture the data as an issue progresses through diff development stages (like audit trail of the issue for specific field in it).

Now I want to build a data model that enables me to capture metrics like avg. amount of time it took for issues to move between 2 stages (for eg, In Progress > UAT). Avg. time for each developer etc.

Above audit trail view would give me data in this format

```
Audit ID | Issue ID| Developer | Issue-stage| Data_Update_dt
A001 | 101 | D01 | In Progress| 31-May-17 00:25:00
A002 | 101 | D01 | UAT | 31-May-17 06:25:00
```

I am trying to understand the design to calculate difference between A002 and A001, time reqd to move from In progress to UAT. What is the best way to do it.

Please advice.

Comment: RDBMS I am using is Oracle

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dimensional model/star schema that has an 'accumulating snapshot fact' as its central fact, with one row per issue as it moves through the system.

[Accumulating Snapshot Facts](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/accumulating-snapshot-fact-table/)

In the fact table you'd include key dates/times for each stage. You'd also be able to add 'lag' measures to the fact, precalculated as the gap between one stage and the next, and/or time spent in a stage.

The fact would be surrounded by dimensions for dates, times and developers.

Then you'd be able to calculate averages on those lags and be able to analyse by developer.

Comment: Thanks. Calculating time using lag() is something to try out. I was thinking of somethign in the lines of scd type 2wherein as new record is added the table, I end date the record and calculate time spent in each stage which at this point will be difference between record created dt and end dt.

Comment: Although you could do a type 2 SCD. Its normally for dimensions, but you can do it for facts if really needed. However I'd say it was better done in one fact row as an accumulating snapshot fact, where there are separate date/times recorded for the dates and times the ticket reached each status, e.g. createddate, devdonedate,testdonedate, donedate.